# How to disable caching in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, passenger, mod-rails

How can I disable caching for my rails site?

I'm running Passenger (mod_rails) and my site is running in 'development' mode:

`'ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'`

Any help?

Comment: What sort of caching? View caching is disabled in development by default.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure... but every time I make a change to a template, I need to restart the rails/Passenger server (via a restart.txt file in the tmp directory). It seems like it's just generalized view caching... not specific to anything. Apologies for my ignorance! :)

Answer (score 8):

By default Passenger will set `RAILS_ENV` to `'production'`. The line `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'` will *only* cause the Rails environment to be set to `'development'` if it has not already set.

You need to add [`RailsEnv development`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env) to your virtual host configuration for the site to make Passenger run Rails in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'll answer this question in case anybody else runs into the same problem. Basically, mod_rails was ignoring my 'development' setting that I had set in the environment.rb file. Adding this to my virtualhost configuration for my site fixed it, however:

`RailsEnv "development"`

See [this link](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#rails_env) for more details.

Hope that helps somebody else!

Comment: It wasn't ignoring it. You told rails that you want to set the environment to 'development' if and only if it's not set yet. See Phil's answer.